# how to get the version of app in testproject?

Tags: android, version, robotium

I am using Robotium to test the apk file of an app. I want to verify the version of given apk and version given in "About" screen is same. Is it possible to get the version of app if i have only apk file? Then how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use apkTool or aapt(conmmand line)

```
aapt dump badging yourapp.apk
```